# Why do I get "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" using Redcloth?

Tags: ruby, redcloth

I'm trying to use Redcloth in my Ruby app, and it's giving me a `wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)` error even though I only have two arguments.

Here's my code:

```
def self.cleanup(string)
  if string == "" || string == nil
    ""
  else

            string = self.iconvert(string, "ascii", "utf8")

    RedCloth.include(RedCloth::Formatters::HTML)
    redcloth = RedCloth.new(string)
    redcloth.html_esc(string)
    string = string.strip
    string = string.gsub(/''/,"\"")
    string = string.gsub(/\r/," ")
    string = string.gsub(/\n/," ")
    string = string.gsub(/\<br \/\>/," ")
    string = string.gsub(/\<br\/\>/," ")
    string = string.gsub(/&nbsp;/," ")
    redcloth.clean_html(string, {})
    string
  end
end
```

This is the source code: http://redcloth.rubyforge.org/classes/RedCloth/Formatters/HTML.html#M000052

```
def clean_html( text, allowed_tags = BASIC_TAGS )
  text.gsub!( /<!\[CDATA\[/, '' )
  text.gsub!( /<(\/*)([A-Za-z]\w*)([^>]*?)(\s?\/?)>/ ) do |m|
  raw = $~
  tag = raw[2].downcase
  if allowed_tags.has_key? tag
    pcs = [tag]
    allowed_tags[tag].each do |prop|
      ['"', "'", ''].each do |q|
        q2 = ( q != '' ? q : '\s' )
        if raw[3] =~ /#{prop}\s*=\s*#{q}([^#{q2}]+)#{q}/i
          attrv = $1
          next if (prop == 'src' or prop == 'href') and not attrv =~ %r{^(http|https|ftp):}
          pcs << "#{prop}=\"#{attrv.gsub('"', '\\"')}\""
          break
        end
      end
```

Here's my log:

```
I, [2013-07-16T12:22:53.095073 #12321]  INFO -- : wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
I, [2013-07-16T12:22:53.095281 #12321]  INFO -- : /home/emai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@edmund/gems/RedCloth-4.2.9/lib/redcloth/formatters/base.rb:46:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because the definition of `method_missing` in that Redcloth source file (base.rb) is defined with just two arguments (and no splat operator) and you are invoking an undefined method with two arguments which, when added to the method name, results in three arguments being passed to `method_missing`.

The offending call appears to be the call to `redcloth.clean_html`. As you noted in your comment, `clean_html` is a private method, so it's not accessible to you through the normal `object.method` invocation mechanism.

Comment: Hey Peter, I think you're on to something. I think I'm including the module improperly. How would I include `RedCloth::Formatters::HTML` in my method and invoke it?

Comment: I'm not as up to speed as I should be on mixing in for Ruby, but if you want to just *use* a gem, you typically just `require` the source file.  Since you're using `include`, you're effectively mixing in those methods to your current class definition, which is not what you want.

Comment: What documentation are you following for determining how to use the gem?

Comment: I'm just writing a small class, so it would be fine if I include the module in my class. I'm using this: http://redcloth.rubyforge.org/classes/RedCloth/Formatters/HTML.html

Comment: Sorry for the continued false alarms on my part as to the method invocation issue.  I can see that `RedCloth.new` is a convenience method for creating `TextileDoc`, which does have an `html_esc` instance method.  So, I think the problem is the `clean_html` call, which I don't think is an instance method of `TextileDoc`.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It's because the `clean_html` method is private in the module. So does that mean there is no way to call it?

Comment: Shoot, I thought I checked for that initially.  Anyway, I think you can bypass the `private` check (see http://philcrissman.com/2009/06/26/rubys-objectsend-can-call-private-and-protected-methods/), but it seems odd that you would have to. This seems like a fairly "polished" gem, the `method_missing` defect notwithstanding, so I would think the functionality should be available in some other supported fashion.

Comment: Hey Peter, I just ended up adding the `sanitize` gem to my ruby app. From what I can see, it looks like my code above is just trying to remove the HTML tags, which is exactly what sanitize does.

Comment: Good. So that I can assist you in the future without delay, would you mind accepting and/or upvoting my answer, assuming you agree that it it addressed your question adequately?